# Creating a folder and setting as workspace using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to create a folder and setting that as the workspace for the rest of the script. However I am not sure why it isn't working.

When I hard wire in a location, the env.workspace can be set to that variable. See script below:

```
import arcpy, datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
date = today.strftime("%Y%m%d_%B_%Y")

folder = r"path\to\folder\\"
arcpy.env.workspace = folder
```

However when I create a folder using CreateFolder tool, and set that variable as the env.workspace, I keep getting an error. The script doesn't run.

```
import arcpy, datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
date = today.strftime("%Y%m%d_%B_%Y")

location = r"path\to\location\\"
folder = arcpy.CreateFolder_management(location, date)

arcpy.env.workspace = folder
```

Comment: Since this is purely a python question with no GIS components, you should ask it on stackoverflow.

Comment: Well its about setting the env,workspace within Arc.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice. You should add the 'arcpy' tag to your question.

Comment: Hasan, I think you can find these types of questions all over GIS.SE. A lot of times the answer is a problem with the code and not with GIS component of the code. However, people still ask and answer here for these types of questions. I can see it going both ways.

Comment: Ive changed the tag to arcpy to avoid confusion.

Comment: What is the error you get? What do you see when you `print(folder)`? Try setting `arcpy.env.workspace = '{}\\{}'.format(location, date)` after creating the folder and see if the script can proceed.

Comment: I get the following error: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 529, in set_
    self[env] = val
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 581, in __setitem__
    ret_ = setattr(self._gp, item, value)
RuntimeError: Object: Error in accessing environment <workspace>

Comment: When I print folder, i get : M:\TEAM_GIS\EDKM\Projects\INSPIRE\INSPIRE_PUBLICATION\2_DATASETS\Datasets_2016_2017\Test\20160803_August_2016 .  I dont get the backslashes at the end which is causing issues with some of the geoprocessing tools further in my script when creating new outputs.

Comment: Another good package to use is os, as it can make new directories and set up paths. I've had good experience with using it and arcpy in same scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work with the following, by adding backslashes to the variable "folder".

```
#Import module
import arcpy, datetime

#Set the date for automatic folder creation
today = datetime.date.today()
date = today.strftime("%Y%m%d_%B_%Y")

#Create and set the workspace
location = r"C:\Test\August"
newfolder = arcpy.CreateFolder_management(location, date)
print "Workspace created"

#Create a variable called folder to be the workspace
folder = str(str(newfolder) + "\\")
arcpy.env.workspace = folder
print folder
C:\Test\August\20160804_August_2016\
```

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
folder = arcpy.CreateFolder_management(location, date)
```

with

```
folder = str(arcpy.CreateFolder_management(location, date)) + "\\"
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. It fails later down the code when trying to locate files within "folder".

Comment: updated to include backslash at end of pathname